# .Net 6 Azure Functions project - include Azure.Worker.FunctionAttribute and Azure.WebJobs.FunctionNameAttribute in same project

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-durable-functions

I'm working on an existing Azure Functions project that contains Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.FunctionAttribute functions.

For example:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;

[Function("TestFunction")]
public async Task Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, 
    FunctionSettings.HttpGet, Route = FunctionSettings.CycleCountEndpoint)] 
    FunctionContext context)
    {
        await _repo.RunSomething();
    }
}
```

After encountering a long running Azure function I would like to create an Azure Durable Function in this same project:
This function looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Net.Http;

public static class TestDurableFunction
{
    [FunctionName("TestDurableFunction")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> 
        HttpStart([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] 
        HttpRequestMessage req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
        ILogger log)
        {
            string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("TestOrchestrator", null);
            log.LogInformation($"Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.");
            return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
}
```

When I run the project, the TestFunction decorated with [Function("TestFunction")] appears in the console.  The Azure.WebJobs.FunctionNameAttribute function does not appear in the console ([FunctionName("TestDurableFunction")])

[image]

Is it possible to make these both work in a .net 6 Azure functions application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to implement both in the same project.

Because `Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker` supports **Isolated Azure Function** whereas `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` supports **In-process Azure Function**.

- Also **Function** tag in `[Function("Function1")]` supports **Isolated Function** and `[FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]` supports **In-Process function.**

I tried to implement the same.

- Created an **Isolated Http Trigger Azure Function**.

**Code:**

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;


[Function("Function1")]
public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
{
    _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

    response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

    return response;
}
```

- Created **Durable Azure Function** with below code.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

[FunctionName("Function1_HttpStart")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
    ILogger log)
{
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("Function1", null);

    log.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);

    return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
}
```

**Response:**

- Could see only the default Isolated Http Trigger Function getting executed.

[image]

[Differences between in-process and isolate worker process .NET Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-in-process-differences)